# Why does `TestFSMRef.receive must throw[Exception]` fail intermittently

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

Hi fellow coders and admired gurus,

I have an actor that implements `FSM` that is required to throw an IOException on certain messages while in a specific state (*Busy*) to be restarted by its *Supervisor*.

**excerpt:**

```
case class ExceptionResonse(errorCode: Int)


when(Busy) {
    case ExceptionResponse(errorCode) =>
      throw new IOException(s"Request failed with error code $errorCode")
}
```

I am trying to test that behavior by using a `TestActorRef` and calling `receive` directly on that expecting receive to throw an `IOException`.

```
case class WhenInStateBusy() extends TestKit(ActorSystem()) with After {
  val myTestFSMRef = TestFSMRef(MyFSM.props)

  ...

  def prepare: Result = {
    // prepares tested actor by going through an initialization sequence
    // including 'expectMsgPfs' for several messages sent from the tested FSM
    // most of my test cases depend on the correctness of that initialization sequence

    // finishing with state busy
    myTestFSMRef.setState(Busy)

    awaitCond(
      myTestFSMRef.stateName == Busy, 
      maxDelay, 
      interval, 
      s"Actor must be in State 'Busy' to proceed, but is ${myTestFSMRef.stateName}"
    )
    success
  }

  def testCase = this {
    prepare and {
      myTestFSMRef.receive(ExceptionResponse(testedCode)) must throwAn[IOException]
    }
  }
}
```

Note: The initialization sequence makes sure, the tested FSM is fully initialized and has setup its internal mutable state. State *Busy* can only be left when the actor receives a certain kind of message that in my test setup has to be provided by the test case, so I am pretty sure the FSM is in the right state.

Now, on my Jenkins server (Ubuntu 14.10) this test case fails in about 1 out of 20 attempts (-> No exception is thrown). However, on my development machine (Mac Os X 10.10.4) I am not able to reproduce the bug. So debugger does not help me.

The tests are run *sequentially* and after each example the test system is shut down.

- Java version 1.7.0_71
- Scala version 2.11.4
- Akka version 2.3.6
- Specs2 version 2.3.13

Can anyone explain why sometimes calling `myTestActorRef.receive(ExceptionResponse(testedCode))` does not result in an `Exception`?

Comment: You don't show where `myTestActorRef` is being created. Is it a typo of `myTestFSMRef` or are they two different objects?

Comment: @mattinbits yes that was a typo, fixed the question

Comment: You were right regarding awaitCond, I was looking at the Java API. Still, an AssertException would fail your test right?

Comment: yes, an AssertionException makes the test fail.

Comment: I found a workaround for my problem in a variant of an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619691/failing-a-scalatest-when-akka-actor-throws-exception-outside-of-the-test-thread). However, I still don't see why this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky question indeed: my prime suspect is that the Actor is not yet initialized. Why is this? When implementing `system.actorOf` (which is used by `TestFSMRef.apply()`) it became clear that there can only be one entity that is responsible for actually starting an Actor, and that is its parent. I tried many different things and all of them were flawed in some way.

But how does that make this test fail?

The basic answer is that with the code you show it is not guaranteed that at the time you execute `setState` the FSM has already been initialized. Especially on (low-powered) Jenkins boxes it may be that the guardian actor does not get scheduled to run for a measurable amount of time. If that is the case then the `startWith` statement in your FSM will override the `setState` because it runs afterwards.

The solution to this would be to send another message to the FSM and expect back the proper response before calling `setState`.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds outright plausible :) I'll have to check back in the office whether the actual test case does that or not, though.

Comment: I am afraid that's not it. The test case expects several other messages from the tested actor without tempering with the state machine, before starting the actual test. I have updated my question to give as close an approximation to the actual code as possible, as I sadly cannot paste the actual code itself.

Comment: Then the only other explanation is that the FSM does something in the background that overrides the state. In general it is not advisable to mix sync and async interactions, and being a TestFSMRef does not ensure that all messages are processed synchronously, notable exceptions being supervisor actions and external interactions.